# How to reload only the visible sections of a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to change the number of items in section depending on the orientation of the device.

I have achieved it by reloading the entire collection view in viewWillTransitionToSize and changing the number of "maximum permissible items in section" in number of sections in UICollectionView.

This is not the best way as I can see we can load specific sections.
Please share if you can come up with a better solution.

Comment: You get the indexPaths of the visible items of the collectionView. Did you try that?

Comment: Actually only the visible items are reloaded anyway

Comment: I tried this @Adeel
-(void)reloadVisibleSections { NSMutableIndexSet *visibleSections = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet]; NSArray *arr = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] valueForKey:@"section"]; for(NSNumber *index in arr) { [visibleSections addIndex:[index unsignedIntegerValue]]; } [self.collectionView reloadSections:visibleSections]; } 
Which is crashing when we rotate the device, may be because the number of visible sections increases when I move from Landscape to Portrait.

Comment: @SanjayPathak please update your question with the code and the crash log.

Answer (score 3):

You can reload a specific section using the code below:

```
let table = UITableView()
let index = IndexSet.init(integer: 0) //The section to reload
table.reloadSections(index, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```

If you want to do it depending of your visible sections you will need to get the visible cells like this:
    `table.visibleCells`

And create the indexes of section to reload from these visible cells

```
let table = UITableView()
var indexes = IndexSet()
let visibleCells = table.visibleCells
for cell in visibleCells {
    indexes.insert((table.indexPath(for: cell)?.section)!)
}
table.reloadSections(indexes, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSSet *visibleSections = [NSSet setWithArray:[[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] valueForKey:@"section"]];
```

//Reloading Section

`[self.myCollectionView reloadSections:visibleSections];`

Comment: the above code is good for tableView. For collectionView
-(void)reloadVisibleSections
{ 
    NSMutableIndexSet *visibleSections = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    NSArray *arr = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] valueForKey:@"section"];
    for(NSNumber *index in arr)
    {
        [visibleSections addIndex:[index unsignedIntegerValue]];
    }
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:visibleSections];
}
Which is crashing when we rotate the device.